# Predefining route for message to take on OMNeT++

Tags: c++, routes, simulation, omnet++, inet

The following image of the network successfully sends messages around in random direction. It is a basic generic network with no specific protocols or connection types.

[image: UK 20 node Network]

Now, I want to be able to simply program the route that the message takes from source node to destination node and everything in between. Say for example I want the message to start from London and be sent to SouthBank, then Manchester, then Preston, and then arrive and be deleted at MiltonKeynes.

The route would then be:
London --> SouthBank --> Manchester --> Preston --> MiltonKeynes

How would I implement this? the OMNeT++ tictoc tutorials (specifically part 4.4 on: https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part4/) only explain how to make the node arrive at a predefined node but the message still travel in random directions in between.

Answer (score 0):

This is called source routing where you explicitly fill inn the routing info at the source node. This is pretty easy to implement. Add a variable size routing info data to the packet you are sending, something like a stack. And provide the names of the cities on the route one by one. Then pop the first element from the stack in the packet, route it towards the city it specifies. All the other nodes should use this algorithm until the stack is empty, when the packet has arrived.

Comment: Many thanks, I understand your stack algorithm, but I'm having trouble implementing it on OMNeT++, specifically it seems like I can't use stack in the .msg file (I assume because stack is C++ but .msg is different?). Also, how do I use "send(msg, "gate$o", k);" in the .cc file (the file that describes the module functionality) when sending the message through the connection to the next node that has been specified by the element at the top of the stack?